# How to prevent form submission on refreshing the page in Zend framework?

Tags: php, post, zend-framework2, page-refresh, unset

This is my action on my controller

```
public function invite()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $data_array                         = $this->getAllParams();
        $emailList                          = explode(",", $data_array['emails']);  
        $message                            = $data_array['message'];

        $error_emails                       = array();


        if(sizeof($emailList) <= 1){
            $this->view->message        = '<div class="alert alert-danger"> Please enter more than one email address and please separate emails by a "," (comma)</div>';    
        }
        else{
            $x = 0;
            foreach($emailList as $singleEmail){

                if (!filter_var(trim($singleEmail), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $error_emails[]             = $singleEmail;
                }
                else{
                    //send emails here
                    $x++;
                }

            }

            if(sizeof($error_emails) > 0){
                $email_str = implode(",",$error_emails);
                if($x > 0 ){
                    $this->view->message    = '<div class="alert alert-success"> Successfully Sent! </div> ';
                }
                $this->view->message        .= '<br /><div class="alert alert-danger"> Message to this emails were not sent! <b>'.$email_str.'</b> <br /> Please enter valid emails!</div>';    
            }else{
                $this->view->message        = '<div class="alert alert-success"> Successfully Sent! </div>';    
            }
        }
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $request->setParam('emails', null);
        $request->setParam('message', null);            
    }

}
```

I tried the solutions i found;
As you can see i tried setParam method to set values to null. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. 
also unset array didn't work- not sure if i did it right. 
Anyway, i don't want to redirect. Just want to unset. Can someone help me out? I've been trying this for few hours now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a header http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and force a revalidation. Sessions/tokens is also another option.

Comment: What is the reason you are avoiding a redirect?

Comment: Why using html's string rather than the controller plugin FlashMessenger ?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not specific to Zend Framework, There is a pattern called PRG (short for Post Redirect Get) to deal with resubmissions of forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Zend Framework provides PRG controller plugin http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#post-redirect-get-plugin In short, it stores post data in session and issues redirect, then on subsequent get request it returns that stored post data.

Example code suggests that you handle form on GET request after PRG plugin did redirect:

```
// Pass in the route/url you want to redirect to after the POST
$prg = $this->prg('/user/register', true);

if ($prg instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response) {
    // returned a response to redirect us
    return $prg;
} elseif ($prg === false) {
    // this wasn't a POST request, but there were no params in the flash messenger
    // probably this is the first time the form was loaded
    return array('form' => $form);
}

// $prg is an array containing the POST params from the previous request
$form->setData($prg);

if($form->isValid()) {
   ...
```

But I disagree with that approach and suggest to always handle form on POST and use PRG to show form with filled data and validation messages afterwards (note `$form` here is an instance of `Zend\Form`):

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $form->setData($this->getRequest()->fromPost());
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //handle form
        // if you don't need to show form again, redirect:
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('some/route');
    }
}

// And now do PRG to re-display form with data and validation errors
$prg = $this->prg('/user/register', true);

if ($prg instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response) {
    // returned a response to redirect us
    return $prg;
} elseif ($prg === false) {
    // this wasn't a POST request, but there were no params in the flash messenger
    // probably this is the first time the form was loaded
    return array('form' => $form);
}

// $prg is an array containing the POST params from the previous request
$form->setData($prg);
// make sure form have validation result to display
$form->isValid();
return array('form' => $form);
```

But since you are not using forms, you will need to validate data manually twice. Once to process and once to display error messages. If you do not want to use Zend\Form component, I would suggest to look at Zend\InputFilter to validate input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSRF protection in zend ie use a token while submitting the form